# Subgroup of an abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I think I have the proof correct, but my group theory is not that strong yet. If there is anything I am missing I would appreciate you pointing it out.

Let $G$ be an abelian group (s.t. $gh = hg$  $\forall g,h\in G$). Show that $H = \{g\in G:g^2=e_G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ where $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$.

Proof:

$1.$ Take $g \in H$. We know $g^2 = e_G$. So, we know $e_G^2 = e_G*e_G = e_G \in H$.

$2.$ Let $g,h \in H \Rightarrow g^2=e_G, h^2=e_G \Rightarrow (gh)^2=g^2h^2=e_G*e_G=e_G$
$\Rightarrow gh\in H$. So we have closure in H.

$3.$ Take $g \in H. g^2=e_G \Rightarrow g*g=e_G \Rightarrow g*(g*g^{-1})=e_G*g^{-1} \Rightarrow g=g^{-1} \Rightarrow g^{-1}\in H.$ So $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$ $\Box$

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: Note that you only need *abelian* for item 2.

Comment: How do I use abelian for item 2? Or did I use it without knowing?

Comment: $(gh)^2$ means $(gh)(gh)$, how do you know that this is equal to $g^2h^2$?

Comment: I guess you really meant to say "Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$" since that's what you showed. Proof looks good to me.

Comment: @user113525 The square of $gh$ is $ghgh$ in a group, and $g^2h^2$ if $g$ and $h$ commute.

Comment: I understand how the abelian nature is required now. Thanks! And yes, I meant to prove that H is a subgroup, I changed it in an edit just now.

Comment: The proof looks fine to me.

Comment: In step 1, I don't see where $g$ is necessary. Showing that $e_G\in H$ is just a matter of showing that $e_G$ satisfies the criterion for membership in $H$, that is, $e_G^2 = e_G$. This is true without reference to any other $g\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very good, but it would be best to *explictly* establish, in proving closure, that $$(gh)^2 = \underbrace{(gh)(gh) = g^2h^2}_{\large G \;\text{is abelian}}$$

I'm not sure if that's what you meant but left that detail out of your proof(?), or if you erroneously made an immediate move by distributing the exponent: $(gh)^2 = g^2 h^2$, which is NOT true, in general.